# NestestedScrollView with RecycleView and ViewPager is not scrolled up views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I'm trying to achieve to scroll views in xml layout which contain recycleview and viewpager but somehow nestedScrollView is not scrolled up the views.

---

layout file.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_200">


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager_media"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />


                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rc_media"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Java file

---

```
    mediaAdapter = new MediaDiscoverAdapter(getActivity(), mediaCallbackListener);
    discoverBinding.rcMedia.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    discoverBinding.nestedScroll.setFillViewport(true);
    discoverBinding.rcMedia.setAdapter(mediaAdapter);
    layoutManager = new StickyHeaderLayoutManager();
    layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    discoverBinding.rcMedia.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution with the help of [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I just make `Viewpager` part of `RecycleView` as row item using `getItemViewType` and removed the `NestedScrollView` so now layout looks like..

*mainLayout.xml*

> 

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="MediaDiscoverFragmentNew"
        type="com.hpc.fragments.media.MediaDiscoverFragmentNew" />
</data>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rc_media"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and created two separate item xmls *raw_media_top.xml* for top `Viewpager` and another *raw_media.xml* for rest of items.

> ```
>       if(viewType == HEADER_VIEW) {
>         RawMediaTopBinding mediaTopBinding = 
>         DataBindingUtil.inflate(mLayoutInflater, R.layout.raw_media_top, parent, false);
>         mediaTopBinding.setMediaDiscoverAdapterNew(this);
>         return new HeaderViewHolder(mediaTopBinding);
>     } else {
>         RawMediaBinding inspirationItemsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(mLayoutInflater, R.layout.raw_media, parent, false);
>         inspirationItemsBinding.setMediaDiscoverAdapterNew(this);
>         return new ItemViewHolder(inspirationItemsBinding);
>     }
> ```

*Cheers!*